# How to upload images too phpmyadmin ASP.Net

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

Hello m trying to upload images to my db how can i do that this is what i have so far

**HTML side**

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="upload" OnClick="Button1_Click1" />
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

**and this is what i have in c#**

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpPostedFile postedFile = FileUpload1.PostedFile;
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
        string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
        int fileSize = postedFile.ContentLength;

        if(fileExtension.ToLower() == ".jpg" || fileExtension.ToLower() == ".png" || fileExtension.ToLower() == ".bmp" || fileExtension.ToLower() == ".gif")
        {
            Stream stream = postedFile.InputStream;
            BinaryReader binaryreader = new BinaryReader(stream);
            byte[] bytes =  binaryreader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);

            string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString;
            string query = "INSERT INTO `images` (`id`,`pic`) VALUES (NULL,@bytes)";
            using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query,conn);
                command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@bytes", bytes));
                int N = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
                Label1.Visible = true;
                Label1.Text = N.ToString();
            }

        }else
        {
            Label1.Visible = true;
            Label1.Text = "Extension is wrong please provide a JPG or PNG Image";
        }

    }
```

and my database is

```
(int)  (blob)
|id  |  pic  |
```

can some one please help me out with this i am actually really stuck :)

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a front-end to your database, MySQL is *the* database. You're connecting to MySQL, not phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with your code except you're using BLOB datatype, I think it'll be better using LONGBLOB instead, I've tested your code and it works, do you get any errors?